# Glue Spark Converting string to datetime - Unable to create Parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose Parquet type is optional binary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to read in partitioned parquet files. And convert a parquet string in this format: `2023-12-10T11:00:00.826+0000` to a timestamp.  I am using this command:

```
df = df.withColumn(
        "etaTs",
        to_timestamp(col("etaTs"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    )
```

There are nulls in some of the parquet partitions. I keep getting this error:

```
`An error occurred while calling o119.collectToPython. Unable to create Parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose Parquet type is optional binary etaTs (UTF8)`
```

I have logged all the types of these columns and they are all strings.  How do I convert these strings to timestamps, why am I getting this error?

Comment: You should share a reproducible code of the error, maybe check your "etaTs" column values, I think there are bad dates in it, probably dates UTF-8 encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a string directly to date_format you desired.

Firstly, you should convert it to timestamp like below and then it can be converted to date_format you wanted.

```py
df = df.withColumn("time_formatted", 
                   date_format(to_timestamp("etaTs", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
                               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

Thanks.